# Vim inside vim-terminal treats Esc as Alt

Tags: terminal

I'm using gVim 9.0 on Windows. Here is the steps to reproduce the issue:

1. Open a vim-terminal with `:term`.
2. Open a vim inside the vim-terminal using command `C:\Windows\vim.bat` in vim-terminal.
3. Enter insert mode and type something more than 5 chars (such as `abcdefg`).
4. Return normal mode with <kbd>Esc</kbd>, and move cursor to column 3 (position of `c`).
5. Press <kbd>i</kbd> to enter insert mode.
6. Press <kbd>Esc</kbd> to exit insert mode. **<-- issue appears**

The <kbd>Esc</kbd> in step 4 is totally fine, but when I type <kbd>Esc</kbd> in the last step, **in about 1 second it won't exit insert mode but acts like I'm pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>**. For example, it will print a `á` if I type <kbd>Esc</kbd> and then <kbd>a</kbd>, as if I pressed <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>a</kbd>. And this vim-terminal is like *corrupted*: I have to exit the vim-terminal and start another fresh one with `:term` to make this issue stop.

I've tried to `set timeout`, `set timeoutlen=1`, `set ttimeout` and `set ttimeoutlen=1`, but it doesn't help.

Is there anyway to resolve this issue?

Comment: What is the value of the `ttimeoutlen` setting (note the two `t`s)? The way Alt keymappings work is that the terminal sends `<Esc>` followed by the key (so `<A-x>` is `<Esc>x`); Vim will wait `ttimeoutlen` milliseconds for the second key (if this value is -1, the value of `timeoutlen` is used, which defaults to 1000, or 1 second). Usually you can set `ttimeoutlen` to something fairly short like `100` or `50`; the only value for long timeouts is slow SSH connections and the like.

Comment: Also see: https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/24938/51

Comment: @MartinTournoij Thank you for this. I checked and my situation is `nottimeout` and `ttimeout=-1`. I’ve tried to set ttimeout to 1, and set ttimeout as well as set ttimeout=1, both in gVim and in the vim inside gvim-terminal, but no avail. However, I’ve found a workaround: use `Ctrl` + `[` for Esc, hehe.

Comment: @MartinTournoij `Ctri`+`[` works exactly the same with `Esc` : (  I found more details about this issue and updated question. Could you review it and see if there is any new idea, if it's not inconvenient for you?