# Can I map Alt+j without mapping Escape followed by j to the same thing?

Tags: key-bindings, terminal, escape

If in insert mode I do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> and then press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>j</kbd>, I see `^[j` inserted, with `^[` being actually a single character.

That's the same I get if I press <kbd>Escape</kbd> followed by <kbd>j</kbd> instead of <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>j</kbd>.

---

I've known that for a long while, but never really understood if it's possible to overcome the undesirable consequences of that.

For instance, if I wanted to map they <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>j</kbd> combo above to something, I'd do

```
nnoremap ^[j something
```

or more readably

```
set <A-j>=^[j
nnoremap <A-j> something
```

but then hitting <kbd>j</kbd> right after <kbd>Escape</kbd> (which would happen only too often) would have the same effect.

Is there a way to work this "mapping identity" between <kbd>Escape</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd>?

Is the terminal emulator I use relevant? I use Vim in URxvt.

Comment: The terminal emulator is [highly relevant](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Get_Alt_key_to_work_in_terminal?useskin=monobook).

Comment: @romainl, I've gone through that link, and apparently there's no bullet-proof solution. However, assuming I'm not interested in using accented letters in normal mode, I would have thought that `nnoremap ê rhs` (`ê` being 0x00ea) would work when I press Alt+j in normal mode, but it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can.

Vim nowaday internally does not map `<A-j>` and `<Esc>j` to the same thing.

In particular there is nothing to do for gVim to make that working.

On some terminals Vim receives the same input for one and the other.

If the characters come super close (the time interval is below `ttimelen`) it will be considered as `<A-j>`.

Otherwise they will be considered for the mapping as `<Esc>j` (unless the time interval is above `timelen` but this is another story)

`timeoutlen` default to 1000 ms = 1s.

`ttimeoulen` is set to 100 ms in `default.vim` but if you don't use `default.vim` you have to set it.

I recommend:

```
set timeout
set ttimeoutlen=100
```

Here is a nice [answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/24938/23502) that explains the difference in more details.

Comment: With `set timeoutlen=5000 | set ttimeoutlen=1 | set <A-j>=^[j | nnoremap <A-j> something` at the end of my `~/.vimrc`, `something` is done even if I press Escape, wait 4 seconds, then press j.

Comment: What is the result of `: set timeout?` and `:set ttimeout?` that control how these timeout duration are considered by Vim?

Comment: `:set timeout?` -> `timeout`, `:set ttimeout?` -> `nottimeout`. But even if do `set ttimeout`, I get the same behavior as in my previous comment.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. It looks odd at first. What is the result of `verbose nmap <esc>j`? Do you have the same result after `:nunmap <esc>j`?

Comment: `:verbose nmap <esc>j` -> `Kitty keyboard protocol: Cleared                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
No mapping found`, therefore `:nunmap <esc>j` -> `E31: no such mapping`.

Comment: Thanks I'm puzzled. I have no access to Linux machine since I'm waiting à plane :-) I'll try to reproduce your problem at home. Maybe an expert like @romainl will pick up ;-)

Comment: @christianbrabandt any idea?

Comment: What happens of you don't set `<A-j>` (remove `set <A-j> <Esc>j`)?

Comment: Then neither of <A-j> and <Esc>j have any effect (well, it's just like I hit j in normal mode).

Comment: Thanks :-) I'm out of ideas ;-)